# RANCID like configuration differ for linux applications

Tags: configuration, diff, file-management

I'm looking for a RANCID-like (http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/) config management tool - the catch is that I want to manage config files for Linux applications like mysql, apache, memcache, varnish, php, and so forth not network configs.

What I'd like the tool to do is:

1) On a periodic basis query a predetermined list of servers (via SFTP/SSH/SCP?)

2) Check if a predetermined list of files have changed (maybe via checksum?)

3) If they've changed, do a diff on the new and old files, email the changes email address.

- This is for change control processes so that a team of people are aware AS changes happen and we have an audit trail. It needs to be real time or quasi real time (within 30 minutes of a change would be acceptable)

4) Commit the new file to a source control repository (SVN/GIT maybe?)

I'm pretty sure RANCID can do most (all?) of this for network devices like Cisco routers, firewalls etc but the problem is it doesn't work for non-network devices (as far as I know). And I lack the perl knowledge and time to code a RANCID module to do the above.

So what I am looking for is a RANCID like turnkey solution (free would be great but I'm not opposed to paying a reasonable price for it) that can do the above. Can anyone recommend anything?

Disclaimer: I'm already aware of centralized configuration tools like Chef and Puppet. While great solutions, at this stage I'm not looking to do automated/centralized config deployments but rather continue to manually manage config files and simply have versioned backups and change notification.

Answer (score 2):

#### etckeeper

The one tool that I've used in the past that does most of what you're looking for is [`etckeeper`](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/).

The backend is configurable so you can choose what ever version control system you want to use (git, svn, bazaar, etc.).

The [primary development page on github](https://github.com/joeyh/etckeeper) has everything you need in terms of  getting started in using it.

#### blueprint

Another tool that might be useful is [blueprint](http://devstructure.com/blueprint/). This tool will collect the customized configurations along with packages you've installed using any of hte package management tools such as packages managed by APT, Yum, RubyGems, Python’s easy_install and pip, PHP’s PEAR and PECL, and Node.js’ NPM.

*excerpt*

> Blueprint is a simple configuration management tool that
>   reverse-engineers servers. It figures out what you’ve done manually,
>   stores it locally in a Git repository, generates code that’s able to
>   recreate your efforts, and helps you deploy those changes to
>   production.

Comment: Can etckeeper store files outside of /etc?

Comment: @Brad - Yes you can - see here: http://serverfault.com/questions/411494/etckeeper-on-customer-directory